# Rspec Change Matcher and factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, rspec3

I'm using factory girl to create my objects. I'm wondering why I have to do the following:

```
RSpec.describe V1::SlotsController, type: :controller do
  let(:valid_slot) { create(:slot) }
  let(:valid_attributes) { attributes_for(:slot) }

  describe "DELETE destroy" do
    it "destroys the requested slot" do
      slot = Slot.create! valid_attributes # not working without this line
      expect {
        delete :destroy, { id: slot.id }
      }.to change(Slot, :count).by(-1)
    end
  end
end
```

If I do not overwrite slot, and just use the one created by factory_girl, the test will not pass. Why that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `let` is ["lazy loaded"](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let). You should use

```
let!(:slot) { create(:slot) }

describe "DELETE destroy" do
  it "destroys the requested slot" do
    expect {
      delete :destroy, { id: slot.id }
    }.to change(Slot, :count).by(-1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Is it save (performance wise) to always use let! (e.g. GET, PATCH) or should it only be used when necessary (e.g. DELETE)?

Comment: You should avoid create unnecessary records in tests to have faster tests. In you example `slot` must be created before running expect block. But be careful here `let!` is out of `describe "DELETE destroy"` and if you add more describes then `slot` will be created each time even if it is not used.